# Getting a dodged bar chart?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I just came across this code that lets me plot multiple ordinates (I know it is a bad notion in the community but I need to do it to compare different metrics). Since this cannot be done inherently in ggplot2, I was wondering if I can adapt the following code to do what I need:

```
twoord.plot(2:10,seq(3,7,by=0.5)+rnorm(9),
  1:15,rev(60:74)+rnorm(15),xlab="Sequence",
  ylab="Ascending values",rylab="Descending values",
  main="Plot with two ordinates - bars on the left",
  type=c("bar","l"),lcol=3,rcol=4)
```

plots the following:

[image]

What I am looking for is to plot multiple bars side to side. I tried replacing `type=c("bar", "l")` with `type=c("bar", "bar")` but that gave me overlapping bars. The exact data I want to plot is the following:

```
Category    SubCat  Value
A           Cat1    0.1
B           Cat1    0.2
A           Cat2    0.3
B           Cat2    0.24
A           Cat3    13
B           Cat3    41
A           Cat4    60
B           Cat4    146
```

I want (A,B) under (Cat1,Cat2) to have the scale on the left, and (A,B) under (Cat3, Cat4) to have the scale on the right and all bars under A and B to be grouped together respectively. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is probably as close as you're going to get using `ggplot2`:

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("Category    SubCat  Value
A           Cat1    0.1
B           Cat1    0.2
A           Cat2    0.3
B           Cat2    0.24
A           Cat3    13
B           Cat3    41
A           Cat4    60
B           Cat4    146"),header = TRUE, sep="")

d$grp <- rep(c('Cat1 - Cat2','Cat3 - Cat4'), each = 4)
ggplot(d,aes(x = Category, y = Value)) + 
    facet_wrap(~grp, scales = "free_y") + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = SubCat), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

This achieves a "dual y axis" by faceting and allowing `ggplot2` to set the axes separately. I'm sure it's possible to get something closer to what you want using base graphics, but it will take some more thought.

**EDIT**

And here's a hack using the `twoord.plot`. Took quite a bit of fiddling, but I've never used that function, so there may be an easier way:

```
par(xaxt = "n") 
twoord.plot(ly = d$Value[1:4],ry = d$Value[5:8], rx = c(9,11,13,15), lx = c(1,3,5,7),
            type = c('bar','bar'), 
            xlim = c(0,16),
            lylim = c(0,0.35),rylim = c(12,150))
par(xaxt="s")           
axis(1, at = c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15),
        labels = paste(d$Category,d$SubCat,sep=""),
        las = 3)
```

[image]